# Location of Console Application from where console is getting loaded?

Tags: weblogic12c

Location of Console Application from where console is getting loaded?

Comment: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe .. Is this console you are looking for?

Comment: Hello PoGibas, My question is related to Weblogic...

Answer (score 0):

WebLogic Server's admin console is hosted by the domain admin server. Application is located under ${WL_HOME}\server\lib\consoleapp in your file system